# Why am I getting this error array index out of bounds

Tags: java

This is the code for my class so far and without the (int) parse it wont compile without an error for sloppy conversion double to int

with this current code it will compile but not run without an exception error in the monthlyFee method

```
public class Bank {


    // instance variables=========================================
    // setup new array of BankAccount objects and internal null constructor
    BankAccount [] custAcct = new BankAccount[10];

    // data above here
    //===========================================================
    // methods down below

    // display methods=======================================

    public void printAccounts(){
        for(int i=0; i<custAcct.length; i++) {
            if (custAcct[i]!=null){
                System.out.println(custAcct[i]);
            }
        }   //end loop

    } // end method

    // utility methods=============================

    public void addAccount(BankAccount acct) {
        for(int i=0; i<custAcct.length; i++) {
            if (custAcct[i]==null){
                custAcct[i] = acct;
                break;
            }
        }   // end loop

    } // end method

    public BankAccount getAccount(int acc) {
        return custAcct[acc];
    } // end method

    public void monthlyFee (double acctVal){
        for(int i=0; i<custAcct.length-1; i++) {
            if (custAcct[i]!=null){
                custAcct[i] = custAcct[(int)acctVal];
                break;
            }
        }   // end loop

    } // end method
```

Comment: It must have to do with the way you call `getAccount` or `monthlyFee`, but we have no idea how you're calling them.

Comment: int errors = 0;
    double fee = -2.95;
    System.out.println("\nCreate bank1");
    Bank bank1 = new Bank();
    System.out.println("\nOne account");
    BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount("Joe Mac", 1234);
    b1.adjust(1000.0);
    bank1.addAccount(b1);
    bank1.printAccounts();
    bank1.printAccounts();
    System.out.println("\nMonthly Fee");
    bank1.monthlyFee(fee);
    bank1.printAccounts();
    System.out.println("\nErrors:");

Comment: `custAcct[(int)acctVal]` doesn't seem right.  If my balance is, say, £100, this would result in custAcc[100], which is outside your bounds.

Comment: Please do not post large snippets of code in comments.  Edit the question and add the code to the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `monthlyFee` method will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line:

```
custAcct[i] = custAcct[(int)acctVal];
```

if `acctVal` is higher than the length of `custAcct` (in this case 10) or lower than 0. From the comment you posted to your question, I see you're calling `monthlyFee` with -2.95, this is the source of your `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Your `addAccount` method may contain a design flaw, too: the way it is currently coded, it fills all of the empty spots in the `custAcct` array with the `BankAccount` that it was passed as an argument. If you only want to add the account to the *first* empty position, use this:

```
public void addAccount(BackAccount acct) {
    for(int i = 0; i < custAcct.length; i++) {
        if(custAcct[i] == null) {
            custAcct[i] = acct;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is the project requirement to have public void monthlyFee(double acctVal)

Comment: I see. Editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this should be coming from here (perhaps sending snippet of stack trace will help)

```
            custAcct[i] = custAcct[(int)acctVal];
```

What value is being passed for acctVal, if the value is less than 0 or greater than equal to custAcct.length then there is a potential of Array out of bound exception. The other issue can be custAcct[i] is not initialized and there is a potential of null pointer exception. Can tell better if you give the stack trace.

Comment: The method monthlyFee takes a double value as a parameter and applies that value to every BankAccount object.

Comment: Is the intent to add/remove acctValue in that case this should be something like             custAcct[i]  += (int)acctVal; so that the value gets incremented or decremented (depending on the sign) in every account accordingly

Comment: //Bank.java:54: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  //              custAcct[i] += (int)acctVal;

Comment: Bank.java:54: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
                custAcct[i] += custAcct[(int)acctVal];
                            ^
  first type:  BankAccount
  second type: BankAccount

Comment: My bad what I really wanted to say was that there should be a method on BankAccount from where you can add monthly fee to each customer's account. Same loop but you simply call the method. Have you implemented that method? if yes then simply call the method where you add to existing balance. If not then you implement that method where you take acctVal passed from Bank classes' monthlyFee method for every account. Assuming BankAccount has a balance field you can do the balance = balance + acctVal or balance += acctVal (assuming acctVal is passed as int)